# Network audit tracker

Tags: nmap

I'm looking for a tool like PBNJ (http://pbnj.sourceforge.net/) but not quite. The functionality I'm looking for is something I can throw into cron to run daily or weekly, scan a network(s), store the findings and produce a diff-like report of hosts and ports that (dis)appeared since the prior scan.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NAGIOS

Its easy to use . And have web interface.

http://www.nagios.org/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already using nagios, and it's not suitable for the requirements I have. I want to provide CIDR ranges to this tool so that it will auto-discover new hosts and/or ports. Nagios does not do auto-discovery.